# What is the yield of a 1kg solid concrete transporter bomb?

Tags: hard-science, teleportation, kinetic-weapons

I want to beam into solid concrete as a bomb. I have transporters and unlike Star Trek I’m not afraid to use them. Terrorists have taken the tech and have *nasty* plans for us.

The bomb is 1 kg sphere of solid concrete, and the target is also a 2m thick solid concrete wall. The ball will be beamed directly into the center of mass making the density of that volume exactly double. Both have equal density ρ = 2,400 kg/m<sup>3</sup>

**Concrete composition**
The concrete in question has quartz aggregate in the following ratios:
[image]

Giving [the following final molecular composition](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Oluwapelumi_Ojuri/publication/275067708/figure/tbl3/AS:669619761201174@1536661200674/Chemical-composition-of-ordinary-portland-cement-as-determined-by-XRF.png):

- CaO = 4%
- SiO<sub>2</sub> = 89%
- Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> = 1%
- H<sub>2</sub>O = 6%

**Calculating number of atoms in the merged mass**
I will use the composition above to invent a "concrete atom" with the average weight of these components. This cement is 64% Oxygen, 30% Silicon, 4% Hydrogen, and 2% Ca or Fe. The weighted average atomic weight of a "concrete atom" is therefore:

$$ \text {Weight of Concrete Atom} = w_\text c = 0.64(w_\text O)+0.3(w_\text {Si})+0.04(w_\text H)+0.02(w_\frac{(Ca+2Fe)}{3}) $$
$$w_\text c = 10.23+8.415+0.04+1.012 = 19.6968 \text{AMU}$$

Therefore, the initial 2kg concrete mass contains $ \frac{2\text{kg}}{19.6968 \text{AMU}} = 6.115\text E{25}$ representative "concrete atoms" in a volume $v_i =  
 \frac{m}{\rho} = 833.3\mu\text m^3$.

Each "concrete atom" shares a volume of space = $ \frac {833.3\mu\text m^3}{6.115\text E{25}} = 1.3627\text E-23\mu\text m^3$ having a diameter:

$$ d = 2r = 2 \sqrt[3]\frac{3(1.3627\text E-23)}{4\pi} = 3.0\text E-8\mu \text m$$

## This math has something wrong... the atoms are not 0.008pm apart in static pressure!

Assume the atoms will align perfectly in between each other.

Neglect the strong nuclear force because no baryonic intersections will occur. Also neglect electromagnetic bonding forces (ionic and covalent), but obviously the other various van der Waals forces apply.

**My assumptions**: the force needed to compress the combined 2kg mass of concrete to 50% of its volume will be the same force exploding the volume of space when its density instantly doubles (but I could be wrong).

Also acceptable is simply calculating the Lennard-Jones Potential energy for the atoms suddenly reducing their distance by 1/2. [image: Lennard-Jones]

The yield calculation should be KE=1/2⋅*m⋅v*<sup>2</sup>

Where *m* is 2 kg, and *v* will be the integral of the velocities of each atom of concrete as the cumulative van der Waals force repels the atoms back toward their van der Waals contact distance.

I believe the final formula can be derived from *W=ΔKE* where Work (W) is the the work done moving the atoms back into their normal density with v<sub>initial</sub> and v<sub>final</sub> Calculated from the force acting on each atom.

I’m hoping for the equation so I can scale it for different yields and possibly different material densities.

**What is the simplified equation for yield in gigajoules for this kind of bomb?**

(I’m calling this a kinetic weapon because the damage is done by accelerating the mass radially outward via nuclear forces.J

Comment: van der Waals interactions happen as a direct result of electromagnetism. What exactly do you mean when you want to 'neglect electromagentic bonding forces'?

Comment: From a classical physics perspective, it's not clear to me whether there will be an explosion as such. You have a compressed piece of concrete. It might just rebound to its equilibrium density and stay there, cracking the wall that surrounds it due to its expansion, but not necessarily flying apart.

Comment: *"Accelerating the mass radially outward via nuclear forces":* make that plain old boring electromagnetic forces. And those electromagnetic forces will *try* to repel the atoms; whether they will succeed or not depends on the strength of the material surrounding the exotic ball. We have real life examples with [tin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin) and other materials which exhibit transition between two solid phases with different densities; no explosion occurs when a piece of tin transitions from white to gray forms or vice-versa.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I think the math will tell us if the energy is sufficient to fly apart. That’s all an explosion is, rebounding to its normal volume - quickly.

Comment: @VogonPoet Taking away ionic and covalent bonds takes away the second most powerful piece of your would-be explosion. (Molecular overlap and the resulting nuclear fusion was the first, which you've also taken away.) Also, at this point it's not a realistic explosion as a result of teleportation. Are you sure you want to remove that?

Comment: @VogonPoet - The law in question is conservation of energy, not force. There's no requirement that the force used to compress it be the force that will act on the molecules once you let go, if only because they won't travel along the same path.

Comment: I'm missing something in my math trying to calculate the average van der Waals radius. I thought dividing the volume of 2kg concrete by the number of atoms gives me the volume per atom, then just calculate the diameter for vdW. I found the "average" atomic weight of each atom is $20.5963 \text{AMU}$ and the 2kg of concrete has volume $$v_i = \frac{m}{\rho} = 833.3\mu\text m^3$$ giving $ \frac{2\text{kg}}{20.5963 \text{AMU}} = 5.848\text E{25}$ representative "concrete atoms" in the combined mass.

Comment: OK, I then calculate that each "atom" occupies $ \frac {833.3\mu\text m^3}{5.848\text E{25}} = 1.425\text E-23\mu\text m^3$ of space. **BUT** that leaves my atoms only 0.03pm apart!?!? $$ d = 2r = 2 \sqrt[3]\frac{3(1.425\text E-23)}{4\pi} = 3.0\text E-8\mu \text m$$ This is BEFORE compression - where did I screw up?

Comment: I need the van der Waals radius to calculate the potential well, which lets me derive the bulk modulus exponent.

Comment: What happens to the air in the room where people beam in?  Why does that not happen to the concrete in the place you beam stuff in?  If you can beam in concrete, why can't you beam in an actual bomb?

Comment: Because [my transporters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/159054/what-would-be-shocking-to-learn-your-neighbor-did-with-his-machine-that-clones-a) don't use magic. Just a wee bit of handwavium. That and concrete is only $4 for 36kg, or 11 cents per bomb

Comment: d *should be* closer to the covalent radius, or ~ 100 - 150pm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I'll give this a whirl.

First of all, found your mistake: you wrote $v_i = \frac{m}{\rho} = 833.3\mu m^3$. Look, that's obviously not the volume of a 2 kg ball of anything. Cubic *microns*? It's one of those things where if you stop to think about it, it clearly doesn't add up. The correct value is $v_i = \frac{m}{\rho} = \frac{2 kg}{2400 kg/m^3} = 8.33*10^{-4} m^3$.

Plugging in your effective number of "concrete atoms," which seems correct to me, we get $7.338*10^{28} \frac{atoms}{m^3}$. I'm going to assume a cubic lattice of atoms, which means we don't have to invert a sphere to get the radius. Simply take this number to the -1/3 power to get an interatomic distance of $2.389*10^{-10} m$, or 2.389 Angstroms. That's a perfectly sensible lattice constant, especially given how many weird assumptions we took to get there.

Now, when the lattices are superimposed, they're not going to neatly line up. There will be some rotation between them, which means a complicated 3D Moire pattern. Thankfully, we have the same lattice constant for both materials, and when we average over all unit cells, Moire patterns just act like a uniform distribution. So basically, the total energy will be the average energy for an extra atom appearing in a random place in a unit cell, times the total number of unit cells.

To get the average energy in a unit cell, we take a 3D Lennard-Jones potential and integrate over a cube of side length $r_m = 2^{1/6} \sigma$ (that's the distance from 0 to the minimum, which will be where the next atom is). We already know this length to be $2.389*10^{-10} m$. But since the potential is spherical and doesn't perfectly match a cubic lattice and there will be barely any energy in the corners anyway, let's just cut it off and integrate a sphere of radius $r_m/2$ instead. Integrating (and using the form of the L-J potential that's in terms of $r_m$):

$4\pi\int_{r_0}^{r_m/2}r^2 dr * \epsilon[(\frac{r_m}{r})^{12} - 2(\frac{r_m}{r})^{6}]$

Here, $r_0$ is a lower-bound cutoff, which we need to make this converge. And that makes sense, since otherwise our randomly-thrown atoms can get arbitrarily close to the repulsive singularities of the other atoms. It's up to you to come up with what you feel is a sensible cutoff.

For the sake of finishing the calculation, I'll pick $4*10^{-11}$ m as the integral's lower bound, which is the atomic size of Neon, including inner electron shells. Neon is close in mass to your "concrete atom," and anyway, the L-J potential is grossly inaccurate even an order of magnitude smaller than this. Now, then, the integral:

$4\pi\int_{r_0}^{r_m/2}r^2 dr * \epsilon[(\frac{r_m}{r})^{12} - 2(\frac{r_m}{r})^{6}]$

$=4\pi\epsilon * \frac{r_m^3}{9}(-464 - 6 \frac{r_m^3}{r_0^3} + \frac{r_m^9}{r_0^9}) \approx \frac{4\pi\epsilon}{9} (\frac{r_m}{r_0})^9 r_m^3$.

As you can see, this answer depends *strongly* on $r_0$, to the point where the calculation is honestly unimportant from a worldbuilding perspective. You can define it to have as much or as little energy as you want just by tweaking this parameter, which depends entirely on how you say your teleportation avoids nuclear collisions.

Anyway, the energy per unit cell is that answer divided by the unit cell volume $r_m^3$. Then multiply by the total number of unit cells to get

$E = \frac{4\pi\epsilon}{9} (\frac{r_m}{r_0})^9 \frac{V}{r_m^3} = \frac{4\pi}{9} * (200 kJ / (6.022 * 10^{23})) * (\frac{2.389 * 10^{-10}}{4*10^{-11}})^9 * \frac{8.33*10^{-4} m^3}{(2.389 * 10^{-10} m)^3}$

$= 2.7 * 10^{14} J$.

or about 65 kilotons of TNT. But like I said, you can change this answer drastically by tweaking $r_0$, which depends on how teleportation in your world works (I assume there's some mechanism for avoiding nuclear intersections anyway). For instance, if you make $r_0$ half as large, which is still reasonable, you get a blast 500 times more powerful. Play with the value of $r_0$ until you get one that you feel is both physically justifiable and fits your story.

Comment: This is great, thanks for finding the error. In the question I specified no baryonic intersections, as well as "atoms will align perfectly in between each-other." I was hoping that would find a minimum

Comment: Also wouldn't we have to subtract the L-J potential at the van der Waals distance (when the atoms have rebounded to σ?

Comment: Edited with a more realistic $r_0$. Anyway, it doesn't make sense for the atoms to align perfectly like that. Even if by some miracle the lattices were aligned in one part of the ball, due to stacking faults, that wouldn't be the case everywhere (this is doubly true for an amorphous material like concrete). If you want a true lower bound, just use something like $r_m / 4$ as your $r_0$ - that keeps the concrete atoms at in the central half of the unit cells. It gives an answer of 1.8 kilotons of TNT - a mere tenth the power of the Hiroshima bomb, rather than 5 times as powerful.

Comment: And no to subtracting the L-J potential at a new distance. At these energies, your lattice will be utterly blown apart (this has the strength of an atomic bomb, after all).

Comment: I asked for the equation and got it! Great!

Answer (score 5):

Thinking about velocities and accelerations is probably the wrong way to approach this.  Better to approach it as a pressure problem.

The change in volume of an object in response to a change in pressure is related to its [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) $B$:

$$\frac{\Delta V}{V} = \frac{P}{B}$$

Where $P$ is the pressure applied.  The bulk modulus of concrete doesn't immediately jump out from Google at me, but might be [something like](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/research/infrastructure/pavements/05062/chapt2c.cfm) 10 gigapascals, meaning that to take a concrete sphere of mass $2m$ (hence volume $2V$) and reduce it to volume $V$ (making the left side of that equation $\frac{1}{2}$), we need a pressure of around 5GPa.

Force is pressure times area, so the work done in compressing the sphere is related to the pressure and the area of the surface of the sphere.  Technically this should be an integral over the reducing radius of the sphere as it shrinks, but as a lower bound we can use the area at the final radius.  To get the volume and radius of a sphere of mass $m$ we need to pull in the density $\rho$:

$$V = \frac{m}\rho = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\implies r = (\frac{3m}{4\pi\rho})^\frac{1}{3}$$

$$F = PA = P \times 4\pi r^2 = (4\pi P)(\frac{3m}{4\pi\rho})^\frac{2}{3}$$

Finally, work done (ie energy stored) is force $F$ times distance-moved-in-direction-of-force $\Delta r$ (this absolutely ought to be an integral), and the radius scales as the cube root of the volume:

$$E = PA \Delta r = (4\pi P)(\frac{3m}{4\pi\rho})^\frac{2}{3}(\frac{3m}{4\pi\rho})^\frac{1}{3} = \frac{3mP}{\rho}$$

Dropping in a value for the density of 2,400 $\mathrm{kg \space m^{-3}}$, we get an energy (for 1kg) of **12.5 megajoules**.  A lot, to be sure, equivalent to around 3kg of TNT, but not spectacular in building-destroying terms.

Comment: This is the same calculation I would do, but I fear you are (as I would be) extending the compressive strength field of application way beyond the reasonable. For **large** compressions that formula does not apply. As a comparison, iron c.s. is small compared to concrete (<1MPa), and the pressure at the Earth's core is predicted to be above 300 **G**Pa. Even so, iron density only increases by less than a factor of three.

Conversely, I *suspect* that increasing concrete density by 200% will yield pressures of Core magnitude, and energies beyond the kiloton range.

Comment: I am very pleased with this start, and he did mention the difficulty finding a bulk modulus for concrete (which will vary greatly depending on the aggregate used). I also think the integral radius is not a difficult calculation...

Comment: ...Wait - I should integrate the Area right?

Comment: $F$ is a function of $r$, so ultimately $\delta E = P(r) A(r) \delta r$, then integrate over $r$.

Comment: You could still make the approximation that $P$ is constant.

Comment: I know that ϵ for Xenon = 1.77 kJ/mol. I will assume concrete will have an aggregate ϵ much larger knowing the great compressive strength. I am hand-waving this to ϵ=200 kJ/mol, knowing this material will at least be over 100 times stronger than Xenon gas.

Comment: I found the solution. Identify a lennard-jones potential energy curve for the material and just reduce the van der Waals radius to 1/2, calculate potential energy between each atom, then convert it to kinetic energy . $$V(r)= 4 \epsilon \left [ {\left (\dfrac{\sigma}{r} \right )}^{12}-{\left (\dfrac{\sigma}{r} \right )}^{6} \right] $$
ϵ  is the *potential well* depth in kJ/mol, σ  is the van der Waals radius (assumed to be normative at static pressure).

Answer (score 0):

That does not sound like the most effective way of using such a weapon. As you can see, the explosive effect is not easy to calculate, and you will presumably have to put in a similar amount of energy to the output.

It takes a specialist 2,000-pound bomb to put a hole in six feet of reinforced concrete; interestingly, kinetic energy and a strong casing is the key, not a large amount of HE.

Might I suggest using the transporter for what it is good at: pinpoint targeting. A ten-gram lump of concrete teleported inside the skull of the target should do the job - even with minimal explosive force -- and will be far more effective than indiscrimate explosions.

Alternatively, use your transporter to teleport fractions of target people away from their current location.